# Angular - Only validate textbox on submit

Tags: angularjs, validation

Is there an ng-show expression I can use to only validate this textbox only when the submit button is clicked? Currently, it's displaying the error message while the user is typing into it.

```
<div ng-show="!vm.validEmployerCode && !form.EmployerCode.$error.required" class="errorMessage">
            You have entered an invalid code
</div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-11">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="Code">Code</label>
                <input ng-model="vm.code" name="Code" type="text" required id="Code" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-md-4">
                Sign Up
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check `$submitted` flag inside your form object, basically that will become a true once you submit the form. So you need to add `form.$submitted` inside `ng-show` directive.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-show="form.$submitted && !vm.validEmployerCode && !form.EmployerCode.$error.required" 
   class="errorMessage">
     You have entered an invalid code
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to supress the error message after the user attempts to submit, gets the error and then enters new input? I would like the message to be hidden while they're typing and fixing the data.